# why mongoDB is so slow to import one million html pages?

Tags: python, mongodb, performance, pymongo

I am new to MongoDB.

Recently, I crawled 2.5 million web pages for personal training purpose. Each page is around 0.1 MB and saved as html file on my hard disk.

I plan to import all the html files into mongodb for further processing, and to accelerate the importing, I used **multiprocessing** model in python. This is my code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import re, sys, os, time, subprocess
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool


    ##connect to default MongoClient
    client = MongoClient()
    ## Link to a database, if the database not exist, create it.
    db = client['mongoF']
    ## create a collection (like a table)
    collection = db['HTMLs']

    shellMSG = subprocess.check_output("find /home/pages_8 -type f", shell=True)
    html_ls =  shellMSG.split('\n')

    def html2mongo(html):
        item = {
            "_id"  : html[-13:-5],
            "category"  : re.search("pages_.*?/(.*)/", html).group(1).split('/'),
            "bs"        : open(html).read()
        }
        collection.insert(item)
        msg = "\rImported " + str(collection.count()) + " files!"
        sys.stdout.write(msg); sys.stdout.flush()  

    t1 = time.time()

    pool = Pool(16)
    pool.map(html2mongo, html_ls) 
    pool.close()  
    pool.join()

    print "\nImporting used " + str(int(time.time() - t1)) + " seconds in total!\n"
```

My computer is a modern game computer, and is very fast. The CPU has 8 cores. And I set the pool number to 16 according to this [blog](http://withr.me/multiprocess-max-number-processess/).

When the above script was executed, I found that only 1.3 million files were imported, because there is no space left on the disk where I store mongoDB database. But the above processing taken more than 7 hours, which I think is very slow.

One more thing that I found is the virtual memory is extremely huge: 372GB!

[Huge VIRT value showed by htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCIDL.jpg)

My question is: 
1. What's the normal speed to import one million such kind of files?
2. What kind of method should I use to improve the importing?

Regards!

Comment: Sorry, I rechecked that each file's size is arround 0.09M. I have imported 1.32 million files, and used 26738 seconds, so the speed is: 1320000 / 26738 * 0.9 MB =  4.4 MB/s. And I know that the writing speed of a modern hard disk should be large than 80MB/s, am I right?

Comment: @withr The speed of hard drive is one thing. The other thing is that AFAIK mongo locks entire collection on each write. Which is obviously inefficient. IMO you shouldn't really use that pseudo-database.